# how do I find a continuos number in dataframe and apply to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, design-patterns

I have a huge dataframe around 5000 rows, I need to find out how many times a pattern occur in a column and add a new column for it, I am able to use np.where to get the pattern to 1 but I don't know how to count the pattern and add to new column, I did a search online try to use loop but I can't figure out how to use loop with dataframe

> `df['P'] = np.where((df['val2'] > df['val1']) & (df['val2']> df['val1'].shift(1)),1,0 )`

```
         Date  val1  val2  P     [new column] ( 
0  2015-02-24   294    68  0         0
1  2015-02-25   155    31  0         0
2  2015-02-26   168   290  1         1            pattern occur 1 time
3  2015-02-27   273   108  0         0
4  2015-02-28    55     9  0         0
5  2015-03-01   273   123  0         0
6  2015-03-02   200    46  0         0
7  2015-03-03    80    83  0         0
8  2015-03-04   181   208  1         1            pattern occur 1 time
9  2015-03-05   195    41  0         0
10 2015-03-06    50   261  1         1            pattern occur 1 time
11 2015-03-07    50   177  0         0
12 2015-03-08   215    60  1         0
13 2015-03-09    13   290  1         2            pattern occur 2 times
14 2015-03-10   208    41  0         0
15 2015-03-11    49   263  1         0
16 2015-03-12   171   244  1         0
17 2015-03-13   218   266  1         0
18 2015-03-14   188   219  1         3            pattern occur 3 times
19 2015-03-15   232   171  0         0
20 2015-03-16   116   196  0         0
21 2015-03-17   262   102  0         0
22 2015-03-18   263   159  0         0
23 2015-03-19   227   160  0         0
24 2015-03-20   103   236  1         0
25 2015-03-21    55   104  1         0
26 2015-03-22    97   109  1         0
27 2015-03-23    38   118  1         4            pattern occur 4 times
28 2015-03-24   163   116  0         0
29 2015-03-25   256    16  0         0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
df['new_column'] = (df.P != df.P.shift()).cumsum() #get an id according to P
mask=df.groupby('new_column')['P'].sum() #what is the total value for each group

duplicated = df.duplicated('new_column',keep='last')
df.loc[~duplicated, ['new_column']] = np.nan #set nan to last rows for each group. We will replace nans with mask

df['new_column'] = df['new_column'].astype(str).replace('\d+', 0,regex=True).replace('nan',np.nan) #convert not nans to zero
mask.index=df[df['new_column'].isnull()].index.to_list()
#If you want to fill the nan values ​​with a series, the index values ​​must be the same. So I replace the index values ​​of the mask series with the index numbers of the nan values ​​in df.

df['new_column']=df['new_column'].fillna(mask).astype(int)
df
'''
          Date  val1  val2  P  new_column
0   2015-02-24   294    68  0           0
1   2015-02-25   155    31  0           0
2   2015-02-26   168   290  1           1
3   2015-02-27   273   108  0           0
4   2015-02-28    55     9  0           0
5   2015-03-01   273   123  0           0
6   2015-03-02   200    46  0           0
7   2015-03-03    80    83  0           0
8   2015-03-04   181   208  1           1
9   2015-03-05   195    41  0           0
10  2015-03-06    50   261  1           1
11  2015-03-07    50   177  0           0
12  2015-03-08   215    60  1           0
13  2015-03-09    13   290  1           2
14  2015-03-10   208    41  0           0
15  2015-03-11    49   263  1           0
16  2015-03-12   171   244  1           0
17  2015-03-13   218   266  1           0
18  2015-03-14   188   219  1           4
19  2015-03-15   232   171  0           0
20  2015-03-16   116   196  0           0
21  2015-03-17   262   102  0           0
22  2015-03-18   263   159  0           0
23  2015-03-19   227   160  0           0
24  2015-03-20   103   236  1           0
25  2015-03-21    55   104  1           0
26  2015-03-22    97   109  1           0
27  2015-03-23    38   118  1           4
28  2015-03-24   163   116  0           0
29  2015-03-25   256    16  0           0

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, considering using `df.iterrows()` is almost never the right way, but it works and you only have 5000 rows of data so efficiency is not paramount.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2015-02-24', 1: '2015-02-25', 2: '2015-02-26', 3: '2015-02-27', 4: '2015-02-28', 5: '2015-03-01', 6: '2015-03-02', 7: '2015-03-03', 8: '2015-03-04', 9: '2015-03-05', 10: '2015-03-06', 11: '2015-03-07', 12: '2015-03-08', 13: '2015-03-09', 14: '2015-03-10', 15: '2015-03-11', 16: '2015-03-12', 17: '2015-03-13', 18: '2015-03-14', 19: '2015-03-15', 20: '2015-03-16', 21: '2015-03-17', 22: '2015-03-18', 23: '2015-03-19', 24: '2015-03-20', 25: '2015-03-21', 26: '2015-03-22', 27: '2015-03-23', 28: '2015-03-24', 29: '2015-03-25'}, 'val1': {0: 294, 1: 155, 2: 168, 3: 273, 4: 55, 5: 273, 6: 200, 7: 80, 8: 181, 9: 195, 10: 50, 11: 50, 12: 215, 13: 13, 14: 208, 15: 49, 16: 171, 17: 218, 18: 188, 19: 232, 20: 116, 21: 262, 22: 263, 23: 227, 24: 103, 25: 55, 26: 97, 27: 38, 28: 163, 29: 256}, 'val2': {0: 68, 1: 31, 2: 290, 3: 108, 4: 9, 5: 123, 6: 46, 7: 83, 8: 208, 9: 41, 10: 261, 11: 177, 12: 60, 13: 290, 14: 41, 15: 263, 16: 244, 17: 266, 18: 219, 19: 171, 20: 196, 21: 102, 22: 159, 23: 160, 24: 236, 25: 104, 26: 109, 27: 118, 28: 116, 29: 16}})

df['P'] = np.where((df['val2'] > df['val1']) & (df['val2']> df['val1'].shift(1)),1,0 )

df['new_column'] = 0
counter = 0

for i, row, in df.iterrows():
    if row.P == 1:
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = 0
    df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = counter

df.new_column = df.new_column * [1 if x == 0 else 0 for x in df.new_column.shift(-1) ]
```

gives

```
          Date  val1  val2  P  new_column
0   2015-02-24   294    68  0           0
1   2015-02-25   155    31  0           0
2   2015-02-26   168   290  1           1
3   2015-02-27   273   108  0           0
4   2015-02-28    55     9  0           0
5   2015-03-01   273   123  0           0
6   2015-03-02   200    46  0           0
7   2015-03-03    80    83  0           0
8   2015-03-04   181   208  1           1
9   2015-03-05   195    41  0           0
10  2015-03-06    50   261  1           0
11  2015-03-07    50   177  1           2
12  2015-03-08   215    60  0           0
13  2015-03-09    13   290  1           1
14  2015-03-10   208    41  0           0
15  2015-03-11    49   263  1           0
16  2015-03-12   171   244  1           0
17  2015-03-13   218   266  1           0
18  2015-03-14   188   219  1           4
19  2015-03-15   232   171  0           0
20  2015-03-16   116   196  0           0
21  2015-03-17   262   102  0           0
22  2015-03-18   263   159  0           0
23  2015-03-19   227   160  0           0
24  2015-03-20   103   236  1           0
25  2015-03-21    55   104  1           0
26  2015-03-22    97   109  1           0
27  2015-03-23    38   118  1           4
28  2015-03-24   163   116  0           0
29  2015-03-25   256    16  0           0
```