# calculate diff between two values and then % difference associated to unique references month by month in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a pandas dataframe;

|  | ID | MONTH | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | REF1 | 1 | 500 |
| 1 | REF1 | 2 | 501 |
| 2 | REF1 | 3 | 620 |
| 3 | REF2 | 8 | 5001 |
| 4 | REF2 | 9 | 5101 |
| 5 | REF2 | 10 | 5701 |
| 6 | REF2 | 11 | 7501 |
| 7 | REF2 | 7 | 6501 |
| 8 | REF2 | 6 | 1501 |

I need to do a comparison between of difference between the ID's previous month's TOTAL.

At the moment I can calculate the difference between the row above but the comparison doesn't take into account the ID/MONTH. Would this need to be a where loop?

I have tried the below, but this returns NaN in all cells of the 'Variance' & 'Variance%' columns;

```
df_all.sort_values(['ID', 'MONTH'], inplace=True)
df_all['Variance'] = df_all['TOTAL'] - df_all.groupby(['ID', 'MONTH'])['TOTAL'].shift()
df_all['Variance%'] = df_all['TOTAL'] - df_all.groupby(['ID', 'MONTH'])['TOTAL'].pct_change()
```

The desired outcome is;

|  | ID | MONTH | TOTAL | Variance | Variance % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | REF1 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | REF1 | 2 | 501 | 1 | 0.2 |

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have edited the original question to show desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the Month by adding 1 (eventually use a more complex logic if you have real dates), then perform a self-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and subtract:

```
df['diff'] = df['TOTAL'].sub(
               df[['ID', 'MONTH']]
               .merge(df.assign(MONTH=df['MONTH'].add(1)),
                      how='left')['TOTAL']
              )
```

Output:

```
     ID  MONTH  TOTAL    diff
0  REF1      1    500     NaN
1  REF1      2    501     1.0
2  REF1      3    620   119.0
3  REF2      8   5001 -1500.0   # 5001 - 6501
4  REF2      9   5101   100.0
5  REF2     10   5701   600.0
6  REF2     11   7501  1800.0
7  REF2      7   6501  5000.0   # 6501 - 1501
8  REF2      6   1501     NaN
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the expected output for clarity?

Comment: hello Mozway, can you take a look at this question ? I believe there may be a better solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74567984/how-do-i-find-a-continuos-number-in-dataframe-and-apply-to-new-column/74571917#74571917

Comment: thank you for your  help - I have updated the original question with the desired outcome. I wish to calculate the variance and then the Variance % difference